# Does the combination of Spring Boot and H2 honor JPA-property javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have a Spring Boot app that is configured to use JPA and its default-provider Hibernate. The app, in environment Non-Local, expects, and, through Oracle, is configured to connect to, an *existing* SQL DB, while the app, in environment Local, must, through H2, *create* it...embedded, in-memory, and private.

The DB utilizes one schema, as seen in this entity:

```
@Entity @Table(schema="foo",name="transactions")
```

Environment Local must, and is configured to, create (after first dropping any existing) tables and their schema. It is the creation, and dropping, of the latter - schema - that exhibits a problem:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists foo.foo_transactions CASCADE
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists foo.foo_transactions CASCADE " via JDBC Statement
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "FOO" not found; SQL statement: drop table if exists foo.foo_transactions CASCADE  [90079-200]
>
> ...and a similar one (Schema not found) for CREATE.

So as to ensure no overlap, in the classpath, between H2 and Oracle, I, in the POM, separate them by build-profile (local and non-local):

```
<profile><id>local</id>...<dependencies><dependency>H2</dependency></dependencies>
<profile><id>non-local</id>...<dependences><dependency>Oracle</dependency></dependencies>
```

My relevant configuration of Spring Boot is:

```
# file application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin...

# file application-local.properties
# blankness of following value masks default configuration, in application.properties
spring.datasource.url=
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas=true
```

That JPA-property, **javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas**, is supposed to do EXACTLY what I desire: create, in addition to tables, any internal schema. Yet, as shown in the aforementioned errors, it doesn't work!

##### Does H2, or the combination of H2, JPA-provider Hibernate, and Spring Boot, not honor it??? Or, have I miscoded/misconfigured something?

I don't want to get bogged down in the following (as the preceding question is my main concern), but for full disclosure...

P.S. If I remove the schema and build and run locally, everything works fine. But, the non-local (Production) flavor mandates that schema, so I must comply, and wish to do so also locally.

P.P.S. I am, indeed, aware of H2's directive 'INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS foo' (to be applied to the datasource URL), and it, if used, does alleviate the problem. However, if I do use it (thereby having to *explicitly* supply a url, thereby conceding Spring Boot's very nice and full auto-configuration [of H2]), it causes another problem, which I need to avoid:

> 2022-08-29 15:43:27.494  WARN 15288 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter: Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]

P.P.P.S. Neither that recommendation (...;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE) nor its sister (...;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1) nor their combination alleviate that problem (attempt to close an already-closed DB).

Answer (score 0):

I've now figured it out - my relevant JPA-property, at least as far as Hibernate is concerned, was slightly wrong...

Whereas I used (as it had once worked for me in EclipseLink, lazily leading me to believe that it was generic to all JPA-providers)

> javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas

I should have used this

> javax.persistence.create-database-schemas